# How to load xml flle in php?

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have a xml file like below. I need to load below xml in php and use xpath to select data

```
<HotelValuedAvailRS xmlns="http://www.sample.com/schemas/2005/06/messages" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sample.com/schemas/2005/06/messages HotelValuedAvailRS.xsd" timeToExpiration="1799840" totalItems="248" echoToken="1667">
   <ServiceHotel xsi:type="ServiceHotel" availToken="eeeeeeeeeee">
      <DirectPayment>N</DirectPayment>
      <ContractList>
         <Contract>
            <Name>FIT-BB1</Name>
            <IncomingOffice code="148"/>
            <Classification code="NOR">Online Price</Classification>
         </Contract>
      </ContractList>
      <DateFrom date="20140925"/>
      <DateTo date="20140928"/>
      <Currency code="USD">US Dollar</Currency>
      <PackageRate>N</PackageRate>
      <TravelAgent>N</TravelAgent>
      <HotelInfo xsi:type="ProductHotel">
         <Code>82383</Code>
         <Name>Rush Inn</Name>
         <Category type="SIMPLE" code="1EST" shortname="1*">1 STAR</Category>
         <Destination type="SIMPLE" code="DXB">
            <Name>Dubai</Name>
            <ZoneList>
               <Zone type="SIMPLE" code="1">Dubai</Zone>
            </ZoneList>
         </Destination>
         <ChildAge ageFrom="0" ageTo="7"/>
         <Position latitude="25.25683000000000077989" longitude="55.29939999999999855618"/>
      </HotelInfo>
      <AvailableRoom>
         <HotelOccupancy>
            <RoomCount>2</RoomCount>
            <Occupancy>
               <AdultCount>2</AdultCount>
               <ChildCount>0</ChildCount>
            </Occupancy>
         </HotelOccupancy>
         <HotelRoom SHRUI="b6Mmi5eA+cW1288Uud+Zsw==" availCount="21" onRequest="N">
            <Board type="SIMPLE" code="BB-E10" shortname="BB">BED AND BREAKFAST</Board>
            <RoomType type="SIMPLE" code="DBL-E10" characteristic="ST">DOUBLE STANDARD</RoomType>
            <ProductType>P</ProductType>
            <Price>
               <Amount>264.360</Amount>
            </Price>
            <CancellationPolicies>
               <CancellationPolicy amount="88.120" dateFrom="20140923" time="2359"/>
            </CancellationPolicies>
         </HotelRoom>
      </AvailableRoom>
      <AvailableRoom>
         <HotelOccupancy>
            <RoomCount>2</RoomCount>
            <Occupancy>
               <AdultCount>2</AdultCount>
               <ChildCount>0</ChildCount>
            </Occupancy>
         </HotelOccupancy>
         <HotelRoom SHRUI="cEMC04/PQQko+zLA8Y/NIw==" availCount="21" onRequest="N">
            <Board type="SIMPLE" code="HB-E10" shortname="HB">HALF BOARD</Board>
            <RoomType type="SIMPLE" code="DBL-E10" characteristic="ST">DOUBLE STANDARD</RoomType>
            <ProductType>P</ProductType>
            <Price>
               <Amount>391.920</Amount>
            </Price>
            <CancellationPolicies>
               <CancellationPolicy amount="130.640" dateFrom="20140923" time="2359"/>
            </CancellationPolicies>
         </HotelRoom>
      </AvailableRoom>
      <AvailableRoom>
         <HotelOccupancy>
            <RoomCount>2</RoomCount>
            <Occupancy>
               <AdultCount>2</AdultCount>
               <ChildCount>0</ChildCount>
            </Occupancy>
         </HotelOccupancy>
         <HotelRoom SHRUI="bgchcL8WV7FA7Pl0Ue5WEg==" availCount="21" onRequest="N">
            <Board type="SIMPLE" code="BB-E10" shortname="BB">BED AND BREAKFAST</Board>
            <RoomType type="SIMPLE" code="TPL-E10" characteristic="ST">TRIPLE STANDARD</RoomType>
            <ProductType>P</ProductType>
            <Price>
               <Amount>419.340</Amount>
            </Price>
            <CancellationPolicies>
               <CancellationPolicy amount="139.780" dateFrom="20140923" time="2359"/>
            </CancellationPolicies>
         </HotelRoom>
      </AvailableRoom>
      <AvailableRoom>
         <HotelOccupancy>
            <RoomCount>2</RoomCount>
            <Occupancy>
               <AdultCount>2</AdultCount>
               <ChildCount>0</ChildCount>
            </Occupancy>
         </HotelOccupancy>
         <HotelRoom SHRUI="8W4RBuMX4NHX5MxDNlqfpQ==" availCount="21" onRequest="N">
            <Board type="SIMPLE" code="HB-E10" shortname="HB">HALF BOARD</Board>
            <RoomType type="SIMPLE" code="TPL-E10" characteristic="ST">TRIPLE STANDARD</RoomType>
            <ProductType>P</ProductType>
            <Price>
               <Amount>546.900</Amount>
            </Price>
            <CancellationPolicies>
               <CancellationPolicy amount="182.300" dateFrom="20140923" time="2359"/>
            </CancellationPolicies>
         </HotelRoom>
      </AvailableRoom>
   </ServiceHotel>
   <ServiceHotel xsi:type="ServiceHotel" availToken="HHHHHHHHHHH">
      <DirectPayment>N</DirectPayment>
      <ContractList>
         <Contract>
            <Name>FIT-BB1</Name>
            <IncomingOffice code="148"/>
            <Classification code="NOR">Online Price</Classification>
         </Contract>
      </ContractList>
      <DateFrom date="20140925"/>
      <DateTo date="20140928"/>
      <Currency code="USD">US Dollar</Currency>
      <PackageRate>N</PackageRate>
      <TravelAgent>N</TravelAgent>
      <HotelInfo xsi:type="ProductHotel">
         <Code>82383</Code>
         <Name>Rush Inn</Name>
         <Category type="SIMPLE" code="1EST" shortname="1*">1 STAR</Category>
         <Destination type="SIMPLE" code="DXB">
            <Name>Dubai</Name>
            <ZoneList>
               <Zone type="SIMPLE" code="1">Dubai</Zone>
            </ZoneList>
         </Destination>
         <ChildAge ageFrom="0" ageTo="7"/>
         <Position latitude="25.25683000000000077989" longitude="55.29939999999999855618"/>
      </HotelInfo>
      <AvailableRoom>
         <HotelOccupancy>
            <RoomCount>2</RoomCount>
            <Occupancy>
               <AdultCount>2</AdultCount>
               <ChildCount>0</ChildCount>
            </Occupancy>
         </HotelOccupancy>
         <HotelRoom SHRUI="b6Mmi5eA+cW1288Uud+Zsw==" availCount="21" onRequest="N">
            <Board type="SIMPLE" code="BB-E10" shortname="BB">BED AND BREAKFAST</Board>
            <RoomType type="SIMPLE" code="DBL-E10" characteristic="ST">DOUBLE STANDARD</RoomType>
            <ProductType>P</ProductType>
            <Price>
               <Amount>264.360</Amount>
            </Price>
            <CancellationPolicies>
               <CancellationPolicy amount="88.120" dateFrom="20140923" time="2359"/>
            </CancellationPolicies>
         </HotelRoom>
      </AvailableRoom>
      <AvailableRoom>
         <HotelOccupancy>
            <RoomCount>2</RoomCount>
            <Occupancy>
               <AdultCount>2</AdultCount>
               <ChildCount>0</ChildCount>
            </Occupancy>
         </HotelOccupancy>
         <HotelRoom SHRUI="cEMC04/PQQko+zLA8Y/NIw==" availCount="21" onRequest="N">
            <Board type="SIMPLE" code="HB-E10" shortname="HB">HALF BOARD</Board>
            <RoomType type="SIMPLE" code="DBL-E10" characteristic="ST">DOUBLE STANDARD</RoomType>
            <ProductType>P</ProductType>
            <Price>
               <Amount>391.920</Amount>
            </Price>
            <CancellationPolicies>
               <CancellationPolicy amount="130.640" dateFrom="20140923" time="2359"/>
            </CancellationPolicies>
         </HotelRoom>
      </AvailableRoom>
      <AvailableRoom>
         <HotelOccupancy>
            <RoomCount>2</RoomCount>
            <Occupancy>
               <AdultCount>2</AdultCount>
               <ChildCount>0</ChildCount>
            </Occupancy>
         </HotelOccupancy>
         <HotelRoom SHRUI="bgchcL8WV7FA7Pl0Ue5WEg==" availCount="21" onRequest="N">
            <Board type="SIMPLE" code="BB-E10" shortname="BB">BED AND BREAKFAST</Board>
            <RoomType type="SIMPLE" code="TPL-E10" characteristic="ST">TRIPLE STANDARD</RoomType>
            <ProductType>P</ProductType>
            <Price>
               <Amount>419.340</Amount>
            </Price>
            <CancellationPolicies>
               <CancellationPolicy amount="139.780" dateFrom="20140923" time="2359"/>
            </CancellationPolicies>
         </HotelRoom>
      </AvailableRoom>
      <AvailableRoom>
         <HotelOccupancy>
            <RoomCount>2</RoomCount>
            <Occupancy>
               <AdultCount>2</AdultCount>
               <ChildCount>0</ChildCount>
            </Occupancy>
         </HotelOccupancy>
         <HotelRoom SHRUI="8W4RBuMX4NHX5MxDNlqfpQ==" availCount="21" onRequest="N">
            <Board type="SIMPLE" code="HB-E10" shortname="HB">HALF BOARD</Board>
            <RoomType type="SIMPLE" code="TPL-E10" characteristic="ST">TRIPLE STANDARD</RoomType>
            <ProductType>P</ProductType>
            <Price>
               <Amount>546.900</Amount>
            </Price>
            <CancellationPolicies>
               <CancellationPolicy amount="182.300" dateFrom="20140923" time="2359"/>
            </CancellationPolicies>
         </HotelRoom>
      </AvailableRoom>
   </ServiceHotel>
</HotelValuedAvailRS>
```

I try like below

```
$xd = simplexml_load_file($rq_request);

foreach($xd->xpath('/HotelValuedAvailRS/ServiceHotel') as $ServiceHotel)
{
    echo $ServiceHotel->AvailableRoom->HotelRoom->RoomType;
}
```

But not working

Comment: You are using $xd3 instead of $xd. simplexml_load_file is not xpath. Look at the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML has default namespace (`xmlns="...")`. The element where default namespace declared and it's descendant elements without prefix and without different default namespace declaration are considered in the same namespace.

So you may need to register a prefix that point to default namespace URI, and use that prefix in your XPath, for example :

```
$xd->registerXPathNamespace("n", "http://www.sample.com/schemas/2005/06/messages");
foreach($xd->xpath('/n:HotelValuedAvailRS/n:ServiceHotel') as $ServiceHotel)
{
    .....
}
```

Comment: You know how to take <Position latitude="25.25683000000000077989" attribute value?

Comment: I don't program in PHP actually, so I don't have any idea on top of my head. I believe you can find information about that on internet. If you can't, just open new question..

Answer (score 0):

Three line xml2array:

```
<?php

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);

?>
```

Simple means simple.  If you know the structure and just want the value of a tag:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlfile);
print $xml->City->Street->Address->HouseColor;
?>
```

Information from [here](http://php.net//manual/ru/book.simplexml.php)